# NestJS handle HttpModule errors

Tags: rxjs, observable, nestjs

NestJS has the following example for using their `HttpModule`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  findAll(): Observable<AxiosResponse<Cat[]>> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3000/cats');
  }
}
```

My question is, how does the client code (most likely a `Controller`) handle this response? How does it treat Observables so that `Cat[]` may be accessed. Or what if the Http request throws an error such as a 404.

How does a NestJS client (Controller) in this case interact with the `findAll()` method provided by the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, the URL you provide to the `HttpService` returns a 404, that error will propagate back through the service, to the controller, and eventually to the client that called the original URL. Under the hood, NestJS will subscribe to all returned Observables so that you don't need to worry about it, you can just return the call directly from your Controller. So in the example above, say we have a controller that looks like this:

```js
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Get()
  findAllCats(): Observable<Cat[]> {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }
}
```

And `CatsService` looks like this

```js
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  findAll(): Observable<Cat[]> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://localhost:3000/cats');
  }
}
```

Assuming you are calling off to *another* server (i.e. this server is not running on port 3000) **and** `/cats` is not a valid endpoint **and** that server returns a 404 to you, the `httpService`'s response will bubble up through the CatsService to the CatsController where NestJS will handle the subscription, and send the response back to the client. If you are looking to do some custom error handling, that will need to be handled in a different way. A great way to test how the `HttpService` responds to things is to create a simple endpoint and call off to a bad URL (like `https://google.com/item` which is a 404)

Comment: I think most of my problems here is my lack of understanding on the fundamentals of Observables which seem to be a core part of NestJS. I guess it's time to brush up on it. Sometimes I don't want to return directly from the controller yet, btw. I was looking for how to handle the data in the controller because it needs to extract from the response before returning anything to the calling client.

Comment: If you are needing to extract data from the Http response, you can do that in a `pipe` of the observable with the `map` operator. The other option could be using an `interceptor` for it. If you are needing some examples with Observables and how Nest uses them, [you can check out my code](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaplay) and see a lot of examples as every database call I make returns an Observable. Observables are definitely a core part, but mostly under the hood because of how adaptable they are to what needs to happen for the framework to function properly

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with NestJs, but if you want to run an observable http request generally you do the following to consume and catchError

```
this.catService.findAll().pipe(
// axio wraps the result in data
map(res=>res.data),
catchError(e=>{
...handle error 404
return of(e)
})).subscribe()
```